# How do i get the twitter return url when authenticating using passport twitter

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, twitter-oauth, passport-twitter

I'm using passport twitter to authenticate and while it does work and redirect me to the main page i want to save the oauth token that's there in the url before it redirects me to my main page as i want to use it to update user's profile image

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out it was pretty simple

i just had to use `req.url` in the `passport.authenticate()` callback function